# Не работает header()

Tags: php

```
if($_GET['code']) {
 $json = @file_get_contents("https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=$api_id&client_secret=$secret_key&code={$_GET['code']}&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri");
 $json_obj = json_decode($json);

 if($json) {
  if($json_obj->user_id and $json_obj->access_token) {
   users::create(array(
    'vk_id' => $json_obj->user_id,
    'ip_address' => ip_address(),
    'date_reg' => full_date(),
    'time_reg' => time(),
    'group' => 1,
    'points' => 300,
    'hash' => hash('ripemd160', time())
   ));

   header('Location: /');
  }
 }
}
```

Странно. Но никуда не перенаправляет.

```
if($json_obj->user_id and $json_obj->access_token) {
```

условие срабатывает. Если вместо header() поставить echo 1;, то оно отобразит.. Пробывал header('Location: /'); exit;, но тоже не перенаправляет никуда. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В том, что вы отправляете заголовки после того, как у вас был вывод на страницу, а предупреждения что headers already sent вы игнорируете настройками. "Для решения этой проблемы нужно функцию header() и всю логику, которая ее вызывает, поместить ДО любого вывода в броузер. Просто перенести повыше в скрипте.
Ведь вы всё равно перенаправляете браузер. То есть, никакой текст всё равно не будет выведен! Значит, и выводить что-то одновременно с заголовком Location нет смысла. Правильно планируйте структуру своего скрипта: блок, который обрабатывает POST, не должен ничего выводить в браузер."

Comment: @stck, благодарю. Действительно, была ошибка, что выводил сначала echo, потом header